# How do I use dictionary to store the filename generated by a method in Python?

Tags: python

I am using a method to generate multiple xml files.
I want to keep track of the files generated by the method using dictionary

```
map = {}
dstFile = f'path-to-dir\\{self.name}.xml'
with open(dstFile,'w') as f_out:
    f_out.write( u'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'+'\n')
    f_out.write( ET.tostring(self.root).decode('UTF-8')
map = {f'{self.name}':f'{self.name}.xml'}
```

But using the `map` dictionary this way, previous values in the dictionary got overwritten

I want that when the method generate a file, its name will get added to the dictionary keeping the older  key value pairs also.

Thanks.

Comment: Add your current code/approach for the same

Comment: @AbhinavMathur I have added

Comment: Change it to ```map[f'{self.name}'] = f'{self.name}.xml'```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```py
map = {f'{self.name}':f'{self.name}.xml'}
```

creates a new dictionary and assigns it to the variable `map`. You want to add a new key-value pair to the existing dictionary.

You can do this the following way:

```py
map[self.name] = f"{self.name}.xml"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dict's method update for example like this:

```
map.update(f'{self.name}'=f'{self.name}.xml')
```